# Absolute path of assets folder

Tags: android

How do I reference the assets from phone memory? I need it to write the absolute path into a html file to load some images which are in assets folder. This html is saved in the phone memory but I can't to save these images in the memory phone because these are very big.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`file:///android_asset/...`, where `...` is the stuff inside your `assets/` directory. Note that will only work within your own process, so you can load the HTML into a `WebView` this way, but not into the Browser application.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in NDK/C++?

Comment: @pree: Not that I am aware of, though you might want to ask a separate StackOverflow question to try to get confirmation of this.