# Access data from Internet and update it into the file in Assests folder

Tags: android, file-io, assets

Is it possible to access data from internet and update it into the file which is present in assets folder. If possible , please tell me the way to achieve this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. The Assets folder is READONLY. Just copy the file to sd and use it from there. you can modify it however you want there.

Here is how you can [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153300/absolute-path-of-assets-folder) the file programatically.

And you can find some code on stack about saving files to SD there are tons of examples here. also don't forget setting the right permissions in the manifest.

For downloading files off the internet: [downloadFiles](http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification)

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in this: a)access data from the Internet. and b)update a file in assets folder. which one you want us to help you with?
Secondly, writing a file in assets folder isn't possible. Why do you want to do that!?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your first question is yes.If you want to parse data then you can parse.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466719/manipulating-data-on-webs-in-android/6466749#6466749). Here you can parse comfortably from any kind of pages.

The answer of your second question is no.Why you want to save the data there.You have the device sdcard.You can save there.The folder(asset) is used by the android for the application's internal purpose